# Проблемы с перегрузкой оператора + в классе матриц

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов, операторы, матрицы

*Только осваиваю ООП, поэтому не судите строго*

Сложение происходит правильно внутри функции, но в main результат не передаётся.

Здесь не хватает некоторых функций, но с ними проблем нет, поэтому не стал писать. Оставил только основные для понимания кода. Я экспериментировал с конструкторами по умолчанию, поэтому не обращайте на это внимание. Раскомментирование деструктора вызывает срабатывание точки останова в файле delete_scalar.cpp.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class MATRIX
{
public:
    MATRIX(int n) { cout << "Конструктор!\n";MATRIX::m = n;  Create(m); Read(m); };
    MATRIX(const MATRIX & c);
    MATRIX() { cout << "Конструктор по умолчанию!\n"; MATRIX::m = 3;  Create(m); Read(m); };
//  ~MATRIX() { cout << "Деструктор!\n"; Delete(m); };
    int det();
    void print();
    MATRIX operator + (const MATRIX& a)const;
private:
    int **matr;
    int m;
    void Create(int);
    void Read(int);
    void Delete(int);
    int Det(int **matr, int n);
    void Get_matr(int **matr, int n, int **temp_matr, int indRow, int indCol);
    void FreeMem(int **matr, int n);
};
MATRIX MATRIX::operator + (const MATRIX& a)const
{
    MATRIX tmp(a.m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            tmp.matr[i][j] = matr[i][j] + a.matr[i][j];
    //tmp.print();
    return tmp;
}
MATRIX::MATRIX(const MATRIX & c)
{
    Create(c.m);
    cout << "Конструктор!\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < c.m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < c.m; j++)
            matr[i][j] = c.matr[i][j];
};
void MATRIX::Create(int m)
{
    matr = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        matr[i] = new int[m];
}
void MATRIX::Read(int m)
{
    ifstream flow;
    flow.open("input.txt");
    int t1; flow >> t1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            flow >> matr[i][j];
    }
    flow.close();
}
void MATRIX::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
void MATRIX::Delete(int m)
{
    if (&matr != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            delete[] matr[i];
        delete[] matr;
    }
}
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include "header_matrix.h"
using namespace std;
ifstream f1;
int main()
{
    {
        setlocale(0, "");
        //----------------------------

        int m;

        //----------------------------

        f1.open("input.txt"); f1 >> m; f1.close();

        //----------------------------

        MATRIX a;
        MATRIX b;
        MATRIX c;

        //----------------------------


        cout << "Det= " << a.det() << "\n";
        a.print(); cout << "\n";
        b.print(); cout << "\n";
    //  a.operator+(b).print();
        c = a + b;
        c.print();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

@AnT Вот так получилось перегрузить оператор присваивания:

```
MATRIX MATRIX::operator = (const MATRIX& a)const
{
    MATRIX tmp(a.m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            tmp.matr[i][j] = a.matr[i][j];
    tmp.print();
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: У вас скорее проблема с оператором присваивания... Его попросту нет (т.е. он генерируется компилятором, и выполняет в результате поверхностное копирование)... А вообще у вас проблем хватает и без этого - вы еще не очень понимаете, как работают классы. Например, вы в каждую функцию передаете `matr` - зачем? Ведь этот указатель и так доступен в каждой функции-члене, поскольку является членом объекта класса. В `Delete` вы же его не передаете? (правда, зачем-то передаете `m`, и проверяете на нулевость не значение `matr`, а ее адрес - который, очевидно, ненулевой...) другое места писать нет :)

Comment: [Правило трех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: "Здесь не хватает некоторых функций, но с ними проблем нет" . Как раз таки проблемы **именно** с "нехваткой функций" (кроме прочего)

Comment: Да, да. Я имел в виду, что некоторые функции типа det я сюда не выкладывал, хоть они и есть в классе, потому что они работают нормально. С передаваемыми m и matr в функции я разобрался, спасибо большое. Насчет оператора присваивания, если я правильно понял, его нужно так же перегрузить? Но все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AnT: Получилось так, что я добился работы программы, но немного не так как я хотел.

```
const MATRIX &MATRIX::operator + (const MATRIX& a)
{
    MATRIX tmp(a.m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            tmp.matr[i][j] = matr[i][j] + a.matr[i][j];
    *this = tmp;
    return *this;
}

const MATRIX &MATRIX::operator = (const MATRIX& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            this->matr[i][j] = a.matr[i][j];
    return (*this);
}
```

Может быть проблема в конструкторе? Но почему-то вариант ниже не работает...

```
MATRIX MATRIX::operator + (const MATRIX& a)const
{
    MATRIX tmp(a.m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            tmp.matr[i][j] = matr[i][j] + a.matr[i][j];
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Отсутствует правильное определение оператора присваивания (а в коде этот оператор используется).
2. Конструктор копирования "забывает" инициализировать поле `m`.
3. По какой-то необъяснимой причине в методы класса зачем-то передается параметр `int m`, который дублирует семантику поля класса `m`. (Попытка исправить таким способом ошибку 2?)
4. `if (&matr != NULL)` - что именно вы пытались проверить таким способом?

Comment: Попробовал перегрузить оператор присваивания. Вот так у меня получилось. Но всё равно не работает.
`MATRIX MATRIX::operator = (const MATRIX& a)const

    {

     MATRIX tmp(a.m);

     for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)

      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)

       tmp.matr[i][j] = a.matr[i][j];

     return tmp;

    }
`

Comment: @Brooding kangoroo: Оператор присваивания должен *присваивать* новое значение тому объекту, который указан в его левой части. Т.е. в реализации оператора присваивания новые данные должны присвиваться именно в `*this`. При этом надо не забыть удалить старые данные, хранившиеся до этого в `*this`. У вас же данные записываются в какой-то посторонний объект `tmp`, который потом просто выбрасывается наружу. А сам `*this` остается нетронутым, т.е. никакого фактического присваивания вообще не происходит.